# Converting from newtype to Int and from Int to newtype

Tags: haskell

How do I convert newtype to Int and vice versa?

I tried:

```
newtype NT1 = NT1 Integer

fromNT1toInt :: NT1 -> Int
fromNT1toInt x = let y = x :: Int
                 in y
```

but I get could't match expected type error

I tried making NT1 instance of Enum class 
but I don't understand well how does toEnum work

```
newtype NT1 = NT1 Integer

instance  Enum NT1 where
toEnum x = let x = x :: Integer
           in if x >= 0
                 then x :: NT1 
                 else x :: NT1
```

when I call toEnum 5 :: NT1 this should return 5 NT1 but I get StackOverflow error.
Where am I making mistake?

Edited: newtype name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fromIntegral` to convert between integral types, such as `Int` and `Integer`. Use `NT1` to convert from `Integer` to `NT1`, and pattern-matching from `NT1` to `Integer`. Finally, you can compose functions to connect things.

```
toNT1 :: Int -> NT1
toNT1 = NT1 . fromIntegral

fromNT1 :: NT1 -> Int
fromNT1 (NT1 x) = fromIntegral x
```

Answer (score 7):

`e :: t` doesn’t mean “convert expression `e` to type `t`”, it’s just an annotation that says “`e` *has type* `t` (already)”. So this:

```
let y = x :: Int in y
```

Means: assert that `x` has type `Int`, set `y` equal to `x`, and return `y`. That’s why you got a type mismatch: `x` does not have type `Int` as you are claiming to the compiler. And this:

```
let x = x :: Integer
in if x >= 0 then x :: NT1 else x :: NT1
```

Means: declare a new variable `x`, set it equal to itself (an infinite loop), asserting that it has type `Integer`, then test whether that infinite loop returns a nonnegative value; either way, return `x`, asserting that it has type `NT1` (this contradicts the `Integer` from before).

To convert between `Integer` and `Int`, you can use `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`, which converts any integral type (such as `Int` or `Integer`) into any numeric type (such as `Int`, `Integer`, `Float`, `Double`, or `Ratio`).

For converting from `newtype`s, you can use pattern-matching:

```
fromNT1ToInt :: NT1 -> Int
fromNT1ToInt (NT1 x) = fromIntegral x
```

Or add a record accessor function to the `newtype` and use that:

```
newtype NT1 = NT1 { nt1Val :: Integer }
-- Note: nt1Val :: NT1 -> Integer

fromNT1ToInt :: NT1 -> Int
fromNT1ToInt nt = fromIntegral (nt1Val nt)
-- Or, with function composition (.):
fromNT1ToInt = fromIntegral . nt1Val
```

Or, finally, use `coerce` from `Data.Coerce`:

```
import Data.Coerce (coerce)

fromNT1ToInt :: NT1 -> Int
fromNT1ToInt nt = fromIntegral (coerce nt :: Integer)
```

And of course, to construct a `newtype` you just use its constructor—in this case, `NT1 :: Integer -> NT1`, e.g. `NT1 5`.